# Using Cordova's hooks in an IBM MobileFirst project

Tags: cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

Cordova supports [Hooks](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/guide_appdev_hooks_index.md.html) that allow scripts to run during the various build and packaging phases.  Useful for typical grunt/gulp tasks of minification and concatenation or Babel compilation.

With the direction shift [coming](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/2015/08/03/integrating-3rd-party-cordova-plug-ins/) with MFP 7.1, will developers be able to use hooks ?

edit:
MFP 7.0 doesn't follow the config.xml convention, so i used the reference hook in the /hooks directory per the cordova documentation. Using MFP-CLI 7.0.0 confirmed that hooks are not executed.

[image: screenshot of example hook per Cordova documentation]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it should be possible for you to use Hooks in a Cordova-type application when using MobileFirst. Those are Cordova apps like any.